# Jquery page transition effect is affecting all divs underneath

Tags: jquery, html, css, web, transition

I'm trying to create smooth page transitions, following a tutorial. It works fine, but whenever I try to add a new div below the one having the effect, it gets the effect too.

this is the script:

```html
$(function() {
    var request = window.location.hash;
    if(request == '#page-2') {
        $('.page.current').removeClass('current');
        $('.page').eq(1).addClass('current');
    }
    $('nav a').click(function(){
        var speed = 200;
        var i = $(this).index();
        $('.page.current').animate({opacity: 0, marginTop:80},speed,function(){
            $(this).removeClass('current');
            $('.page').eq(i).css('marginTop',30).animate({opacity:1,marginTop: 50},speed).addClass('current');
        });
    });
});
```

This is the html and css for the page (footer is the div having the issue).

```css
html {
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

body > div, nav {
    width:640px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:50px;
}

.page {
    display:none;
    opacity:0;
}
.page.current {
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang=lipsum>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>smooth page transition</title>
        <link rel=stylesheet href='style.css'>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <nav>
            <a href='#page-1'>first page</a>
            <a href='#page-2'>second page</a>
        </nav>
        <div class='page current'>
           page1
        </div>
        <div class='page'>
           page2
        </div>
 <div id='footer'>
THIS GETS THE SAME EFFECT!!!
 </div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: hi@ Lana I have a little confuse what do you want for your case

Comment: I want to have the footer div to not have a transition effect when I click on the menu buttons. Now when I click the buttons, the footer has an effect, the same way the pages do.

Comment: **[Something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/dwpL4jL0/)**?

Comment: Hopefully I have dealt with you problem as following code

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao has a great way to handle your issue too

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao I tried this solution, the problem is, whenever my upper div will have too much text, the footer will no longer be below it :/

Comment: yea because it has `position fixed` and `bottom 0` and it is one of the easiest way you can avoid _`transition`_.. Because you cannot avoid `transition` on `floating` elements as their position will be changed when other elements hide and show up in the `DOM`

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. It does solve the problem having the animation go from left to right rather than up/down. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Lana if you have done your problem ,you can feedback your answer by yourself in add answer ,by the way you can get some reputations if you do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code , I just modify one line in your code , hopefully it is you want. Thanks,Willie
PS: I just lock your position, please modify your left px other.

```
           ===========================================================================
             <!--   <div class='page current' STYLE="position:absolute;left:500px;">-->
           ===========================================================================


        <!doctype html>
        <html lang=lipsum>
        <head>
            <meta charset=utf-8>
            <title>smooth page transition</title>
            <link rel=stylesheet href='style.css'>
 <style>
           html {
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }

    body > div, nav {
        width:640px;
        margin:auto;
        margin-top:50px;
    }

    .page {
        display:none;
        opacity:0;
    }
    .page.current {
        display:block;
        opacity:1;
    }
       </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav>
                <a href='#page-1'>first page</a>
                <a href='#page-2'>second page</a>
            </nav>
            <div class='page current' STYLE="position:absolute;left:500px;">
                page1
            </div>
            <div class='page'>
                page2
            </div>
            <div id='footer'>
                THIS GETS THE SAME EFFECT!!!
            </div>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
            <input type="text" value="aa" />

        </body>
    </html>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var request = window.location.hash;
            if (request == '#page-2') {
                $('.page.current').removeClass('current');
                $('.page').eq(1).addClass('current');
            }
            $('nav a').click(function () {
                var speed = 200;
                var i = $(this).index();
                $('.page.current').animate({ opacity: 0, marginTop: 80, opacity: 0, marginBottom: 100 }, speed, function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('current');
                    $('.page').eq(i).css('marginTop', 30).animate({ opacity: 1, marginTop: 20 ,opacity: 1, marginBottom: 70 }, speed).addClass('current');
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately whenever I try this and then add more text in the page, it still exceeds and writes on top of the footer. I'm thinking something is wrong with the script, that it's targeting an incorrect div, or something like that.